# Computer switches off main power supply?

Tags: boot, power-supply, power, water-damage

Ok so I managed to pour water all over my keyboard, mouse, monitor, and power boards. I've dried everything up, everything works except my monitor has water inside it making a little patch (i've placed it out in the sun is this a good idea to dry up the water inside?). My actual computer didn't get any water on it but whenever I try to connect it to power it triggers the safety switch for all the wall sockets (so everything in the house connected to a wall socket is switched off) how can I fix this?*

*As soon as I connect it to a power board/wall socket it switches on for a split second and then everything switches off.

The computer shutdown almost instantly when the water was spilt if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

tldr: You probably might possibly be a danger to yourself and others at this point, and you computer might possibly catch fire or you nay be putting yourself at risk of electrical shock. DO NOT ATTEMPT TO TURN ON THE PC.

That said, its probably useful to analyse the problem in some minor depth to understand what's going on.

Basically your breakers tripping is probably the equivilent of having a serious pain in your side. Something clearly is wrong - be it an alien parasite, government tracker being installed wrongly and causing infection, or plain old appendicitis.

This wikipedia article is a good place to start if you want to educate yourself on [breakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_leakage_circuit_breaker).

On the bright side you've isolated the problem to your PC, and most PC components run on 12V DC or less. Chances are your power supply is faulty, and there's a higher than normal voltage somewhere that's connected to earth. This is a very bad thing. Household voltage can be *lethal* or at the very least very very painful. I'd certainly try replacing the power supply. While usually I'd benchtest the old power supply, in this case its likely too much of a risk.

Even if the PSU is replaced, there's no guarantee that the rest of the system is entirely functional. Tap water may contain some dissolved minerals that are bad for your system. I;d start with the PSU however, test to see what works and if there's any issues and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Given you got water inside the powerboard, I would try replacing that first.

Turn on your computer without the peripherals to make sure you haven't done any damage to it. Then re-add each peripheral separately.

Comment: I've tried removing all peripherals and using different wall sockets around my house, (the powerboard still works, my modem, monitors and printer are running off it). Basically anytime I try to switch my computer on it switches triggers the safety switch stopping all power in  the house.

Comment: Does anything work in that wall socket the comp was originally plugged into?

Comment: Yes, its just my comp thats the problem i think

Comment: Yeah, sounds it. You got any spare parts like a PSU?

Comment: I don't think so. Is it the PSU that's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Ever heard of a short-circuit?

When the computer has a short-circuit, the main power shuts off to prevent a fire in your house. If it wouldn't switch off, some hundred amperes of current would run throguh your cables in the house, in the computer, and right back in the other wire, producing a lot of heat in the process. Some piece of it would start to burn, and set your house on fire.

Comment: Thanks man, how should I go about fixing it?